# Espaçamento de duas divs com bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou duas divs que estão coladas uma na outra e queria dar um epaçamento vertical nelas, porém nao estou fazendo certo. 
estou usando o bootstrap

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

espaço entre o botão do arquivo e o botão de salvar no caso

```
<div >
   <div >
      <span>
      Arquivo Referente a Requisição
      <input class="btn btn-file" data-icon="false" type:"file"   />
      </span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <button>Salvar</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual versão do Bootstrap vc está usando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem vários jeitos de fazer isso. No seu caso pode usar uma `margin`.:

> A propriedade margin do CSS define a área de margem nos quatro lados
>   do elemento. É uma abreviação que define todas as margens individuais
>   de uma só vez: margin-top, margin-right, margin-bottom, e margin-left.

Portanto, para o seu caso basta colocar uma `margin-bottom` na `div` do `input` e definir a distância. Veja:

```css
.upload-file {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  margin-bottom: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div>
   <div class="upload-file">
      <span>
      Arquivo Referente a Requisição
      <input type = "file"/>
      </span>
   </div>
   <div>
      <button>Salvar</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Observação: No seu input type file você tem um pequeno erro, está usando no HTML um `type: 'file'`, o correto seria: `type = 'file', com um`=``.

**Referências**

- [margin MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/margin)
- [padding MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/padding)